# find matching substring in a list with multiple condition

Tags: python, json

I have multiple lists.

```
item1 = [
    "4bff652c-a589-4cb0-b28f-0745e199ae88-ppp.json",
    "40e10f09-9d53-4891-a4d4-d2885e5492af-vvv.json",
    "065aa522-a458-44d6-9894-7e928d422c35-a.json",
    "5ba3fcb2-8fae-4847-a631-9d57acb6885c.json"
]

item2 = [
    "fa28f1ba-5532-4ff8-945d-70f5b57a7733-ppp.json",
    "ee65f5b5-1333-47f3-8eca-49b63fa35a62-a.json",
    "9bc518d8-84b4-4032-9ed8-4bb78559a9a0.json",
    "a20bc0c3-ff61-4df5-90c5-695c7614222e-b.json"
]

item3 = [
    "6e1cb404-9494-4e2d-a4c7-16c62bf440ce-vvv.json",
    "a3b3e94c-fe69-4304-8129-2137a6407479-a.json"
]
```

I want to find if any of the above lists have an item ending with both -ppp.json and -vvv.json.

from the above example, the correct answer is item1.

I have tried with

```
for i in item1:
  if i.endswith("-ppp.json") and i.endswith("-vvv.json"):
     print(i)
     #do some opertion
```

But the above code is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward solution. At first, you check if there are `vvv` and `ppp` items. Then, if they are, you do your operation

```
item1 = ["4bff652c-a589-4cb0-b28f-0745e199ae88-ppp.json",
"40e10f09-9d53-4891-a4d4-d2885e5492af-vvv.json",
"065aa522-a458-44d6-9894-7e928d422c35-a.json",
"5ba3fcb2-8fae-4847-a631-9d57acb6885c.json"]


item1_contains_ppp = False
item1_contains_vvv = False

for i in item1:
    if i.endswith("-ppp.json"):
        item1_contains_ppp = True
        
    if i.endswith("-vvv.json"):
        item1_contains_vvv = True
        
if item1_contains_vvv and item1_contains_ppp:
    ...
    #do some operation
```

Answer (score 0):

For each list, you may try:

```
ppp = 0
vvv = 0

for item in lst:
    if re.search(r'-ppp\.json$', item):
        ppp = 1
    if re.search(r'-vvv\.json$', item):
        vvv = 1

if ppp + vvv == 2:
    print("List matches")
else:
    print("List does not match")
```

This approach uses two separate variables to keep track of whether a list entry has been seen ending in either `-ppp.json` or `-vvv.json`.  If both have been seen, the list is reported as a pass, otherwise it is reported as a failure.

Answer (score 0):

An approach like the following would work:

```
def check_endings(items):
    return all(any(l) for l in zip(*[(bool(re.match(".*-ppp.json$", i)), bool(re.match(".*-vvv.json$", i))) for i in items]))

print(check_endings(item1))
print(check_endings(item2))
print(check_endings(item3))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
True
False
False
```

In essence:

- you go through each element of the list with a list comprehension
- A list of tuples, formed by two booleans, is created. For example, for `item1` you get

```
[(True, False), (False, True), (False, False), (False, False)]
```

given that the first element ends with `-ppp.json` and the second with `-vvv.json`.

- Using `zip(*` you *transpose* the list of tuples, getting

```
[(True, False, False, False), (False, True, False, False)]
```

each vector tells you if you have for `-ppp.json` or `-vvv.json`, respectively.

- With `any` you check if there is at least one `True` in each list; finally, with `all` you verify that both lists have `True` values

It has to be noticed that the `bool` cast in the list comprehension is not necessary (a `Match` is a *true-ish* element), but I used it to facilitate the explanation:

```
def check_endings(items):
    return all(any(l) for l in zip(*[(re.match(".*-ppp.json$", i), re.match(".*-vvv.json$", i)) for i in items]))
```

In addition, it has to be stressed that you may not need to check all the elements to conclude that a specific list satisfies your conditions: for example, you know that list `item1` is good just after 2 elements. In that case:

```
def check_endings(items):
    res = [False, False]
    for item in items:
        if re.match(".*-ppp.json$", item):
            res[0] = True
        elif  re.match(".*-vvv.json$", item):
            res[1] = True
        if all(res):
            return True
    return False
```

This may make a difference for very big lists - note that `if all(res)` is *inside* the loop